# Retrying module not retrying on exception

Tags: python, exception, urllib2

I am trying to retry a function whenever an exception is raised using the retrying module. However, it never retries even though there is an exception. For example, take a look at the code snippet below. It should retry 10 times with a random interval for the second URL in `url_list` and then fail. Can anyone tell me why it's not retrying?

```
import urllib2
from retrying import retry


def retry_if_exception(exception):
    """Return True if we should retry (in this case when it's any Exception), False otherwise"""
    return isinstance(exception, Exception)


@retry(retry_on_exception=retry_if_exception, wait_random_min=1000, wait_random_max=1500, stop_max_attempt_number=10)
def start_http_request(url):
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        print response
    except Exception as err:
        retry_if_exception(err)
        print (err.reason)

url_list = ['https://www.google.ca', 'http://goo123213.ca', 'http://code.activestate.com']

for url in url_list:
    print url
    start_http_request(url)
```

References:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for `retrying`, `retry_on_exception` is supposed to be a function that returns `True` if it should be retried. You're supplying it with a type, instead. Try this:

```
@retry(retry_on_exception=lambda e: True, wait_random_min=1000, wait_random_max=1500, stop_max_attempt_number=10)
```

...which should tell it to retry on each failure.

Answer (score 0):

You should review the docs, you're not doing it right:

`retry_on_exception` expects a function which will be called to determine if it should retry... if you want to do it on any exception, just leave it off:

```
@retry(wait_random_min=1000, wait_random_max=1500, stop_max_attempt_number=10)
```

If you want to specify specific conditions:

```
@retry(retry_on_exception=retry_if_exception,wait_random_min=1000, wait_random_max=1500, stop_max_attempt_number=10)

def retry_if_exception(exception):
    """Return True if we should retry (in this case when it's any Exception), False otherwise"""
    return isinstance(exception, Exception)
```

Comment: You are right, my bad. However, I changed the code (updated above) still not retrying.

Comment: @Rihan If you want to retry on all exceptions, you don't have to specify an exception type. See my updated answer

Comment: Magic, you are spot on. I would also like to add, the root cause of the problem was I was trying to catch exception manually within the retry block, removing it solved the problem.